# taking automatic photos windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, camera, photos

I want my windows phone application to take automatic photos without the users intervention.
The cameraCaptureTask.Show() method opens the camera application and this is not what I want to do. I want to be able to take photos without asking the user to click on anything. 
how can I do that?

Comment: using a PhotoCamera class..

Answer (score 0):

Use `PhotoCaptureDevice` documented here: [Capturing photos for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207050%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

However, when do you want to take photos? What is the logic behind it? Be aware that your application must be running to take photos programmatically.

Comment: I need my app to take photos without the user pressing on any button. for example, I want to take a photo if the app has detected a shout. I assume that at that moment the user cant take a photo by himself and I want my app to automaticly take it for him.

Comment: Using the above class you can take a photo whenever you want.